# Crystal - Multiple 'Where' Clauses within the same Table

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is a sample of my data set

[image]

I want to report to check for two different set of 'where' values and then only return data where both conditions are met.  I can get the report to work when I use a single check, but not when using more than 1.

I want to return results where ActualFinish for LIbraryTaskID=409 is within a selected date range AND where ActualFinish for LibraryTaskID=555 is null  (these have a common scheduleID which I use to grab additional data)

When I use the following it will work for a single 'select'

```
({ScheduleTasks.LibraryTaskID}=409 and {ScheduleTasks.ActualFinish} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date})
```

However, when I try to add a second clause it fails.

```
({ScheduleTasks.LibraryTaskID}=409 and {ScheduleTasks.ActualFinish} in {?Start Date} to {?End Date})
AND
({ScheduleTasks.LibraryTaskID}=555 and isnull({ScheduleTasks.ActualFinish}))
```

How can I accomplish this?  Its simple to do in SQL, but not sure how to make Crystal do it.  I tried to just use the single select and then a suppress where the second condition was null, but that not work either.

Comment: Are you trying this condition in selection formula?(you are not written) also are you try with or condition. This means in your ActualFinish column is not null with 555 condition. check by drag the fields in detail section.

Answer (score 0):

try like below:

```
    ({ScheduleTasks.LibraryTaskID} = 409 or {ScheduleTasks.LibraryTaskID}=555) 
and (isnull({ScheduleTasks.ActualFinish}) or {ScheduleTasks.ActualFinish} in     
{?Start Date} to {?End Date})
```